# Secure string visible on azure logic app parameters window

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am fetching value from key vault but it my secure string is visible in parameter windows in azure logic app. how can I hide it from this window?

## dev.logic.parameters.json File:

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "logicAppName": {
          "value": "gaf-ir-dev-publisheventtosfplatform-logicapp"
        },
        "salesforce-client-secret": {
          "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
              "id": "/subscriptions/42187cc7-b2ae-423a-9039-00298be79cdf/resourceGroups/ir-dev-use-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/ir-dev-use-kv"
            },
            "secretName": "SalesforceClientSecret"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

## LogicApp.json File

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 80,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Logic App."
      }
    },
    
    "salesforce-client-secret": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "salesforce-client-secret"
      }
    }
            }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "LogicApp"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": "..."
          "parameters": {            
            "salesforce-client-secret": {
              "type": "securestring",
              "defaultValue": "[parameters('salesforce-client-secret')]"
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
            "manual": {
              "type": "Request",
              "kind": "Http",
              "inputs": {
                "schema": {}
              }
            }
          },
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {}
        },
        "parameters": {}
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

## Parameters Window:

[image]

As you can see it is showing secret value in default value text box. It should not be visible in the parameters window.

Comment: Why not simply fetch it using the built action rather than through the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Storing secret values and secret objects in a parameter is not suggested as mentioned in MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-parameters-workflows?tabs=consumption).
[image]

Check if below scenario helps in your case,

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. I have secret stored in azure key vault and retrieving the value using Get secret action and I have enabled secure input and output so that it will not show in run history window.
   [image]
3. Using the secret value in http action and getting data.
4. The secret value will not be visible in run history window,
   [image]

**Note:** As mentioned by @Skin, you can use built in actions like variables and assign secret value to variable. So that you can use value throughout logic app using variable and you can secure it using settings option.